# Как составить правильный запрос на MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Значит есть такая проблема,есть таблица, с двумя столбцами SUMMA и DATE. Дата в формате Timestamp. Есть в таблице 3 значения допустим такие:

SUMMA       DATE

3000        2014-06-01

2000        2014-06-02

1000        2014-06-03

Так вот. Есть поле Input куда пользователь вводит дату. Например такую 2014-06-03. 
Через метод POST передаю в обработчик и записываю данные в переменную $date.
И ему должно вернуть только последнее значение. т.е 1000    2014-06-03.
Сделал такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE(my_table.date) BETWEEN '$date' AND NOW();
```

Даже если будут данные после 03 июня он получит все записи. Так вот , есть задача, что нужно посчитать сумму полей до $date.
Т.е. этих полей:

SUMMA       DATE

3000        2014-06-01

2000        2014-06-02

Но если напишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE(my_table.date) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '$date';
```

То он еще посчитает сумму включенного поля.
Помогите как составить правильный запрос.
Спасибо!

Comment: Так:

    SELECT SUM(summa) FROM my_table WHERE my_table.`date` < $date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин написал, и тут же сам разобрался как сделать.
Вот запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE(my_table.date) NOT BETWEEN '$date' AND NOW();
```

Спасибо!